# custom ListView in a Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, xml, listview, android-studio, android-dialogfragment

I have looked for solutions on google followed several tutorials and also checked for answer here before uploading.

When I activate the Dialog Fragment it appears empty. it won't load my ListView no matter what I do.

Here are my codes: 
Dialog Fragment Code:

```
public class MonthDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private Context context;

private String[] monthsArr = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr",
        "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.month_fragment_item, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.month_fragment_list_view);
    MonthItemAdapter adapter = new MonthItemAdapter(context, monthsArr);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    builder.setView(view);
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;
}
```

This is the List Adapter:

```
public class MonthItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
private Context context;
private String[] months;
private TextView monthName;

public MonthItemAdapter (Context context, String[] months ){
    super(context, R.layout.month_list_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.months = months;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.month_list_item,null);
        monthName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.month_list_item_text_view);
        convertView.setTag(monthName);
    }else{
        monthName = (TextView) convertView.getTag();
    }
    monthName.setText(months[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

And this is how i summon the dialog fragment:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == etMonth.getId()) {
        monthFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you implemented the getCount() method

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return months.length;
    }
```

Comment: what do i need it for?

Comment: You just need to implement this method in your adapter class to tell the adapter about the count of items you needed in list

Comment: using a A persistent single-choice list from AlertBuilder solved my problem.

Comment: @Shay what do you mean by "persistent single-choice list" ?? and if you have posted your actual code in question then notice you are using a custom Adapter that badly needs the getCount() method to be implemented. I guess in your solution you are passing any built-in Adapter with your data source  to the ListView e.g ArrayAdapter.